# How to get the max date from a specific foreign key from SQL Server?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server

I am creating an application in NodeJs.
In this I have a SQL Server database in which I save data and perform queries.

One of these queries in particular doesn't work for me, I think it's due to my inexperience with SQL.

The step table stores the steps performed by a subject throughout history, so it can have one or more steps (one or more rows in the table with the same contact_id but different dates->(FECHA)).

I am using this query, but it returns empty.

```
SELECT FECHA, id_contacto FROM step WHERE id_contacto = 680 
AND FECHA = (SELECT MAX(FECHA) FROM step).
```

What I want to obtain is the last step of the subject 680, that is, for all the possible steps of the contact 680, obtain the one where DATE is the largest.

this is the structure of the table.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are there `NULL` values in the column fetcha?

Comment: It would return no rows if the max date in the table does not belong to id 680.

Comment: Your 2 `where` conditions do not match, so your outer condition includes `id_contacto = 680` but you max condition doesn't, so will be looking at ALL steps. Change `(SELECT MAX(FECHA) FROM step)` to `(SELECT MAX(FECHA) FROM step where id_contacto = 680)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume we have table with two records
id_contacto=1 FECHA='2022-09-30'
id_contacto=680 FECHA='2021-10-31'

Your subquery

```
 SELECT MAX(FECHA) FROM step
```

returns '2022-09-30' (maximum date in the table)
then your query is

```
SELECT FECHA, id_contacto FROM step WHERE id_contacto = 680 
 AND FECHA ='2022-09-30'
```

table does not contain the required data, so resultset is empty